# Loop through DataRow and update stock levels

Tags: c#, datagridview, sql-server-ce

In my application the user creates quotations using a DataGridView. The user inserts data into the DataGridView via another form, then its inserted into a new created unique table. When the user wants to invoice a customer, they open a form displaying the a DataGridView of the table they just created. On a button click I'd like to generate a PDF File of the invoice (This I already know how to do, so don't answer in regards to that) and update the stock levels in the table "stockTBL"

My code so far sort of works, it loops through all of the rows, but doesn't subtract the amount I'm actually trying to invoice (In this case, 2 items, both with a quantity of 1) It subtracts 9 from each item.

Here is my code :

```
   private void updateStock()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; k++)
                {



                    {
                        string constring = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\LWADataBase.sdf";
                        string Query = "UPDATE stockTBL SET Quantity = Quantity - @quantity where [Item Name] = @name";
                        using (SqlCeConnection conDataBase = new SqlCeConnection(constring))
                        using (SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(Query, conDataBase))
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                conDataBase.Open();

                                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@name", Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value)));
                                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@quantity", Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value)));
                              int rowsUpdated = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                conDataBase.Close();

                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

**I'm using C#2010 and SqlCe 3.5**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess that you have a gridview with 9 columns, such that your two rows look approximately like this:

data0   | data1   | data2   | data3   | 1 | data5   | data6   | data7   | data8

data0.1 | data1.1 | data2.1 | data3.1 | 1 | data5.1 | data6.1 | data7.1 | data8.1

---

First, you loop over the rows to perform your task for each row.  However, then you loop over each column.  With each iteration, you are performing:

```
string Query = "UPDATE stockTBL SET Quantity = Quantity - @quantity where [Item Name] = @name";
```

Note that the quantity you reduce by remains the same each time through (the value in cell 4 for your current row)

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@quantity", Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value)));
```

To fix this, try removing the second part of your loop so that it only performs the reduction on each item one time.

```
for (int k = 0; k < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; k++)
```

Final Code:

```
private void updateStock()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            string constring = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\LWADataBase.sdf";
            string Query = "UPDATE stockTBL SET Quantity = Quantity - @quantity where [Item Name] = @name";
            using (SqlCeConnection conDataBase = new SqlCeConnection(constring))
            using (SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(Query, conDataBase))
            {
                try
                {
                    conDataBase.Open();

                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@name", Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value)));
                    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlCeParameter("@quantity", Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value)));
                    int rowsUpdated = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    conDataBase.Close();

                 }
                 catch (Exception ex)
                 {
                     MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                 }
              }
          }
      }
```